# Google maps with android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Tiles of google maps are not loading on actual device while it works on emulator?How should i solve this problem?

Comment: check your network connectivity is there or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My android skills may be a little rusty, but have you generated a debug API key? If so, have you added **INTERNET** to the application manifest?

**Example**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Take a look at the following page [Obtaining a Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html). Concise instructions are
provided for generating both a release and a debug API key.

Comment: Its seem that it work on emulator so MAP API key must not be problem

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need to switch to the release key in your layout. You should have two MAP API keys, one for the emulator and one for the release version of the application.

Comment: To load the tiles do i require that application should be compiled in release mode

Comment: Yes, you'll need to compile in release mode, with the release MAP API key, in order for the tiles to be loaded on the device.

Answer (score 0):

try to adding this in Android Manifest file.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```